# How to hide default value in model from displaying in form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

In my razor form I have this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.User.TotalSales)
```

Because the User object isn't null, the value of TotalSales defaults to 0, and that displays in the form.

Is there a way to blank this out using the built-in helper, or do I have to do this via javascript or something?

I am afraid if I have to do this via javascript, when the user posts the form and there are errors, my javascript will again wipe that textbox when it shouldn't.

Comment: Make totalSales nullable and assign it null when a model is created

Answer (score 1):

In my app I did properties nullable and marked them with RequiredAttribute.

Comment: Mine is a required frield, and I don't want nullables in my db table.

Comment: I use to create separate models for MVC. So it's not a problem to have non-nullable property in DB model and nullable in view model. Of course it requires additional effort, but make possible to put more data in model instead of ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check before you output the textbox:

```
@if (vm.User.TotalSales != 0)
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.User.TotalSales)
}
else{
    Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.User.TotalSales.Age, new { @Value = "" }) 
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the vm.User is never null, the issue is the property TotalSales is an int, and defaults to 0.  So the form textbox defaults with the value 0 in it, I want it to be blank.

Comment: Yes, i don't want the default value of 0.

Comment: OK, I added an else-clause which outputs the textbox but with an empty  value. I also edited the check

Answer (score 0):

use model validation with required attribute. something like this.

```
[Required]
 public int age{ get; set; }
```